Why not Past Perfect

I arrived at the airport in time to kiss Linda good-bye before the plane took off.

Why is Past Perfect never used  in such cases? One action clearly happens before the other, why not “had arrived”?

Americans tend not to use the past perfect if simple past will be understood similarly.

@Barmar that’s the thing, with this “in time” construction Brits use Past Simple only too.

You don't need to use past perfect if the order of events is obvious. Please search for similar questions.

The past perfect isn't required in this particular context. If the narrator was telling the story from the perspective of a later time, they might say "I remembered that I had arrived at the airport in time to kiss Linda goodbye before the plane took off."

No particular tense has to be used. Rather, we use the tense that refers to the time and order of events that is important to us. For example:

I arrived at the airport in time to kiss Linda good-bye before the plane took off.

We might assume here that the key time marker is the arrival at the airport. A simple past tense does this, and other markers (in time to..., before...) are used to clarify the relative timing.
On the other hand:

I had arrived at the airport before the plane took off, so I was in time to kiss Linda good-bye.

Here the basic content of the sentence is the same, but we can sense a different emphasis. This time the main point is that I was able to say good bye to Linda. In this context the relative order of me arriving and the plane leaving is far more important. The past perfect can reinforce this.
Note though that even in the second sentence the past perfect is not compulsory. It's simply available as a literary tool.
Note also that the original question shows this understanding instinctively. The question says, One question clearly happens before the other. Not One question clearly had happened before the other. A present tense here is valid because we are describe the current relationship between the tenses as we study them now.
